# Are there any nontrivial second Hurewicz homomorphisms for familiar compact 6-dimensional manifolds?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, group-homomorphism, compact-manifolds

Based on several computations I have done, it seems that the second Hurewicz homomorphism $$h:\pi_{2}(X)\rightarrow H_{2}(X;\mathbf{Z})$$ has a habit of being trivial.  For instance, this seems to be the case for $X=S^{6}, \mathbf{RP}^{6},$ and $\mathbf{T}^{6}$, as well as for all compact symplectic groups $Sp(n)$, unitary groups $U(n)$, and special unitary groups $U(n)$, as well as the orthogonal groups $O(n)$ for $n\geq 4$ (which are the ones I care about for my problem).

This leaves me wondering: are there any compact, familiar, even-dimensional manifolds (dimension at least $6$) for which the second Hurewicz homomorphism *isn't* trivial?

If there aren't, would any of you happen to know any less familiar or less elementary examples that fit the bill?

Comment: All of the spaces you describe are just spaces for which $\pi_2$ vanishes, which doesn't have anything to do with the Hurewicz homomorphism.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, that's how I know they don't work for me.

Comment: $S^2 \times [0,1]^{2k}, k\geq 2$ answers your question, if you view $S^2$ as familiar.

Comment: @DanielValenzuela Affirmative, sir.

Answer (score 2):

What about a simple connected 6 dimesional manifold whose 2nd homology group is not trivial, i.e $S^2\times S^4$.

By Kunneth formula we know that $H_2\neq 0$. And by Hurewicz theorem, $h$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Just take $X=S^2\times T^4$. To obtain such a manifold.